# Unresolved reference: when i am trying to access view using view binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewbinding

I am working on an Ecommerce app, where i am getting data from an online api. After getting data I am trying to get them inside my recycler view. Here i am using View Binding to bind my xml view with the activity using a Recycler View and its adapter. So the problem arise here and it says Unresolved Reference to my View IDS

Errors:

```
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (25, 21): Unresolved reference: hotProductsScreenProgressBar
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (25, 50): Variable expected
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (29, 25): Unresolved reference: hotProductsScreenProgressBar
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (29, 54): Variable expected
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (33, 25): Unresolved reference: hotProductsScreenProgressBar
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (33, 54): Variable expected
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (43, 21): Unresolved reference: hotProductsScreenProgressBar
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (43, 50): Variable expected
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (47, 47): Unresolved reference: hotProductsScreenRecyclerView
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (49, 9): Unresolved reference: adapter
e: /Users/gama/Desktop/essStore/app/src/main/java/com/example/essstore/view/HotProducts.kt: (50, 9): Unresolved reference: layoutManager
```

Activity

```
class HotProducts : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = "Hot Products"
    private  lateinit var productAdapter: SimpleProductsAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityHotProductsBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityHotProductsBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setUpRecyclerView()
        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            binding.hotProductsScreenProgressBar.isVisible = true
            val response= try {
                RetrofitInstance.api.getTodos()
            } catch (e: IOException){
                binding.hotProductsScreenProgressBar.isVisible = false
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: You might not have internet connection!")
                return@launchWhenCreated
            }catch (e: HttpException){
                binding.hotProductsScreenProgressBar.isVisible = false
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: Unexpected Response!")
                return@launchWhenCreated
            }
            if(response.isSuccessful && response.body()!=null){
                productAdapter.products = response.body()!!
            }
            else{
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException: Unexpected Response!")
            }
            binding.hotProductsScreenProgressBar.isVisible = false
        }
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() = binding.hotProductsScreenRecyclerView.apply{
        productAdapter = SimpleProductsAdapter()
        adapter = productAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@HotProducts)

    }
}
```

Here is my Adapter Class

```
package com.example.essstore.data

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.AsyncListDiffer
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DiffUtil
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.essstore.databinding.GeneralProductCardBinding

class SimpleProductsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder>() {

    inner class ProductViewHolder (val binding: GeneralProductCardBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

    private val difCallBack= object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<product>(){
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: product, newItem: product): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: product, newItem: product): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    private val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, difCallBack)
    var products: List<product>
        set(value) {
            differ.submitList(value)
        }
        get() = differ.currentList


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
        return ProductViewHolder(
            GeneralProductCardBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.binding.apply {
            val product = products[position]
            generalProductCardTitle.text = product.productName
            generalProductCardDescription.text = product.productDescription
            generalProductCardPrice.text = "$ ${product.productPrice}"
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return products.size
    }
}
```

Here is my XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".view.HotProducts">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/_btn_profile_screen_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:text="Hot Products"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/_hot_products_screen_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/_hot_products_screen_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/general_product_card"/>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Kindly Help me out! I tried many solutions but they didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the leading underscore from all view `id`s in the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_color"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".view.HotProducts">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_profile_screen_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_back"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    ...

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/hot_products_screen_progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

        ...

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/hot_products_screen_recycler_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:listitem="@layout/general_product_card"/>

        ...

</LinearLayout>
```